# I am not able to make mysqli_stmt_num_rows make work in php

Tags: php

i have been trying to make mysqli_stmt_num_rows function work but I can't seem to get either an error with mysqli_error and to me everything seems fine.

```
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email= ? ;");

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);

    if  (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $query)) {
        echo "Error at mysqli_stmt_prepare ". 
                mysqli_stmt_error($connection);
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $userEmail );

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

        if  (!$result) {
            echo 'Error at $result'. mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        } else {
            echo '$result is working :)';
        }
    }
```

I can make work of mysqli_stmt_get_result but not mysqli_stmt_num_rows. help :(

Comment: That is not how you should check if your query is working.

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php - Full of useful info and examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` returns a number in the range `0` to `n` it does not return a boolean.

You are testing `$result` as if it were a boolean!

Now if your query returns NO ROWS, which it will if this is a new user  `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` will return ZERO and

```
if  (!$result) {
```

will see ZERO as FALSE and therefore run the

```
    echo 'Error at $result'. mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
```

However as this is NOT an error `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)` will not return an error message.

You should be doing

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

if  ($result > 0 ) {
    echo 'Found that user';
} else {
    echo 'Nobody yet registered with that email';
}
```

Comment: hahaaa haaa
So basicallay mysqli_stmt_num_rows is working but it is not returning anything so it is giving a null in term of Boolean? :D

Comment: Well it might be giving a ZERO which equates to FALSE. Simple test is echo the output from `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` like `echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)`

Comment: Thanks :) you rock